# Выбор одного или нескольких файлов пользователем. Проблема с onActivityResult

Tags: java, android

Необходимо реализовать выбор нескольких файлов пользователем. Есть следующий код:

```
public void performFileSearch() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = null;
        ClipData clip = resultData.getClipData();
        for(int i = 0; i < clip.getItemCount(); i++) {
            ClipData.Item item = clip.getItemAt(i);
            uri = item.getUri();
            Log.i(TAG, "Uri: " + uri.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Данный код работает хорошо, если выбирать от 2 файлов. Если выбирать 1, то:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=777, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:284877 flg=0x43 }} to activity {com.example.myapp/com.example.mytestapp.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.ClipData.getItemCount()' on a null object reference
```

Как сделать, чтобы была возможность выбрать и один, и несколько файлов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все просто, я делаю так:

```
 ArrayList<String> fileUris=new ArrayList<>();
 if(intent.getData()==null) { //detecting multiple selection
        ClipData clipdata;
        clipdata = intent.getClipData();
        for (int i=0; clipdata!=null && i < clipdata.getItemCount(); i++)
           fileUris.add(clipdata.getItemAt(i).getUri().toString());
    }
 else { //single selection
        fileUris.add(intent.getData().toString());
 }
```